# Auto-expand to the bottom of the page [CSS]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the blue element to expand to the bottom of the page.
But if I set the `height: 100%` to it, then it does expands beyond the bottom of the page. I think it does that because it doesn't take in consideration the size of the red element and then together with the size of the red element they go more that 100% of the parent.

[image]

How do I know that it expand beyond the page? Because the parent element have borders that then are shorter than the blue element.
[image]

The code looks like that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    :root {
        --body-backroung-color: #e7e8e5
    }

    html, body {
        height: 100vh;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
        background-color: var(--body-backroung-color);
    }

    .main-content {
        padding: 25px;
    }

    .zero-margin-lr {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .page-margin-lr {
        margin-left: 9em;
        margin-right: 9em;
        border-left: solid 0.1em gray;
        border-right: solid 0.1em gray;
    }



    .main-content-custom {
        background-color: #e9ecef;
    }

    .jumbotron-custom {
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    }

    .content {
        margin-bottom: 1em
    }
</style>
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <div class="container-flex page-margin-lr">
  <!--RED ELEMENT-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>.</h1>
      </div>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']"
                 routerLinkActive="active">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--  BLUE ELEMENT-->
  <div class="row main-content-custom zero-margin-lr">
    <div class="col-2"></div>

    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="main-content">
        <form name="newPost" #newPost="ngForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="content">Content</label>
            <textarea id="content" name="content" class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="author">Author</label>
            <input id="author" name="author" type="text" class="form-control"/>
          </div>

          <div class="text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Post</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The snippet above is inside the body element. The `html` and `body` have `height: 100%`

How can I make the blue element expand to the bottom of the page but don't go beyond/outside of the parent element?

Comment: Can you put up a working snippet ?

Comment: I updated my post to add a working snippet. It should work now. @ZohirSalak

Comment: A working code snippet people can just copy paste and see the problem exactly like you do.

Comment: I updated the code. It is now a 100% working code snippet. Just copy it inside a file with .html postfix and double click it. But it was not that easy to extract it in one file. @ZohirSalak

Comment: Added `height:100%` nothing happened, Also the container only have left and right borders ?

Comment: Yes, it has only left and right borders. I tried to add `display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%` to the parent element and `height: 100%;` to the blue element. It makes the blue element to expand to the bottom of the page. But if I add some more elements (with javascript) under the `<form>` element, the the blue element doesn't expand automatically to the bottom?! I don't understand this behavior!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean anyway if you want a flex item to fill the remaining space without going outside give it `flex-grow:1;`

Comment: It doesn't worked but anyway thnx!

Comment: When you say 100% on a flex item it will take 100% height of it's parent which is more than just the renaming space if there's any. Here's a demo illustrating `flex-grow:1;` https://jsfiddle.net/eu40jmv8/1/

Comment: Yes, that is my problem. I added the `flex: 1 0 auto;` to the element I want to expand until the bottom of the page like in your example. But it doesn't works in my case: https://jsfiddle.net/6jhg5e4z/3/. In case to see the problem, you should increase the size of the display windows in JSFiddle. Then you see that the element doesn't expand to the end of the page.

Comment: It will only expand if the parent have empty space, the problem is that your parent's height depends on the content so there's no empty space.

Comment: That is my question. I want the parent and then the child element to expand to the bottom/end of the page. Also I want too the parent and the child to expand if I add more elements inside the child element. Like a combination of height: 100; for expand to the end and height: auto; expand automatically when more elements are added (new element will be added under the <form> element).

Comment: Try `min-height:100vh` on the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for me was:

- add `height: auto; min-height: 100vh` to the parent.
- add `flex: 1` to the child/blue element

Thank you to Zohir Salak for heling a lot.